# Access source entity/model in IValueConverter in Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to access a property of source model inside an IValueConverter but could not figure-out how to do that.
I am mapping `Project` to `ProjectWithUrl`.

The `ProjectWithUrl` is converted using a converter `ProjectIdToUrlConverter` which takes `Project.Id` as source parameter and returns a string which is set in `ProjectWithUrl.Url`.

Here's the Profile:

```
CreateMap<Domain.Entities.Project, ProjectWithUrl>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Url, x => x.ConvertUsing<ProjectIdToUrlConverter, string>(y => y.Id))
            ;
```

Here's the Value Converter:

```
internal class ProjectIdToUrlConverter : IValueConverter<string, string>
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public ProjectIdToUrlConverter(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public string Convert(string sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //I need to check if Project.SomeProperty (string) is null or not.

        //Get Url using Project.Id.
        Task<string> result = _mediator.Send(new GetProjectAudioUrlQuery { Id = sourceMember });
        return result.Result;
    }
}
```

**So, how can I access `Project.SomeProperty` inside `IValueConverter`?**

*Note: I am already passing source member. I need to access other property.*

Do I have to use Type Converters?

Comment: You need a value resolver instead.

Comment: It has destination but I need source. public string Resolve(string source, ProjectWithUrl destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context);

Comment: Check the docs for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer so that other folks landing here can find the solution easily.

I was able to access all the properties of source entity/model using the IValueResolver implementation instead of IValueConverter.

Thanks Lucian for directing me in the right direction.

I implemented the `IValueResolver<in TSource, in TDestination, TDestMember>` interface which injects the whole source model instead of just the source member.

*One must be aware before using the IValueResolver that it is specific to a model/entity meaning that you cannot reuse it for other models while the IValueConverter can be used for multiple models.*

Here's my solution:

```
internal class ProjectIdToUrlConverter : IValueResolver<Domain.Entities.Project, ProjectWithUrl, string>
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public ProjectIdToUrlConverter(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public string Resolve(Domain.Entities.Project source, ProjectWithUrl destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //Proceed only if SomeProperty is not null.
        if (source.SomeProperty != null)
        {
            //Returns Url if the file is present in the blob.
            Task<string> result = _mediator.Send(new GetProjectAudioUrlQuery { Id = source.Id });
            return result.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            //Return null if the SomeProperty is null.
            
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Mapping is configured:

```
CreateMap<Domain.Entities.Project, ProjectWithUrl>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Url, x => x.MapFrom<ProjectIdToUrlConverter>())
            ;
```

Comment: You can still use a value converter if you explicitly pass the needed value at `Map` time using `context.Items`.